# Rails how do I extract (and copy) only certain attributes from an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Rails 5, I want to create a new instance of an Author model, but in the process I want to copy only a subset of the attribute values (columns) from my User model.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
user = User.first
Author.create user.attributes.without("id", "token", "secret", "created_at", "updated_at", "active", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip")
```

The User.first method works and returns a valid user from the table. However, the Author.create line doesn't work. I'm getting a NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass error.

Here is my User table from the schema.rb file:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider",                               null: false
    t.string   "uid",                                    null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "token"
    t.string   "secret"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "active",                 default: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "screen_name"
    t.integer  "followers"
    t.integer  "following"
    t.integer  "statuses"
    t.integer  "listed"
    t.integer  "lists"
    t.integer  "favorites"
    t.integer  "views",                  default: 0
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "first_name",             default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "last_name",              default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.index ["active"], name: "index_users_on_active", using: :btree
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["provider", "uid"], name: "index_users_on_provider_and_uid", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["provider"], name: "index_users_on_provider", using: :btree
    t.index ["uid"], name: "index_users_on_uid", using: :btree
end
```

And here is my Author table:

```
create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "uid",                     null: false
    t.string   "provider",                null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.string   "url"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "screen_name"
    t.integer  "followers",   default: 0
    t.integer  "following",   default: 0
    t.integer  "statuses",    default: 0
    t.integer  "listed",      default: 0
    t.integer  "lists",       default: 0
    t.integer  "favorites",   default: 0
    t.integer  "views",       default: 0
    t.string   "website"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.index ["provider"], name: "index_authors_on_provider", using: :btree
    t.index ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_authors_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["uid"], name: "index_authors_on_uid", using: :btree
end
```

As you can see, the new Author table has many of the same columns/attributes as the User table, but I only want to copy across a subset of the User attributes (columns and values) when creating the new Author object.

Maybe the user.attributes.without method isn't the right one?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it via [slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) since `user.attributes` is just a hash of values.

```
user.attributes.slice('name', 'location')
```

Comment: [Since Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5345) the `slice` method is also available directly on an ActiveRecord object. The method has [since been moved into ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44544) making it more generally available. This simplifies the above to just: `user.slice 'name', 'location'`